# Error 'loading android-aarch64/libmongo_embedded_capi.so' for MongoDB Mobile

Tags: android, mongodb, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use MongoDB Mobile (beta) in my Android app. I've folowed the steps as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/build-mobile/)

This is the code that is executed:

```
final StitchAppClient client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("<APP ID>");

final MongoClient mobileClient = client.getServiceClient(LocalMongoDbService.clientFactory);
```

the first line works but when the second line is executed the app crashes with this error:

```
 com.mongodb.embedded.client.MongoClientEmbeddedException: Failed to load the mongodb library: 'mongo_embedded_capi'.
     Unable to load library 'mongo_embedded_capi': Native library (android-aarch64/libmongo_embedded_capi.so) not found in resource path (.) 

     Please set the library location by either:
     - Adding it to the classpath.
     - Setting 'jna.library.path' system property
     - Configuring it in the 'MongoEmbeddedSettings.builder().libraryPath' method.
```

**This library is not incuded in the download provided by mongoDB, but apperantly is still needed. Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem from mongoDB.**

The device im using is a Oneplus 6 with the arm64-v8a libraries from mongoDB in this location: `app\src\main\jniLibs\arm64-v8a`

for reference, this is my build.gradle:

build.gradle(Project: App):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module: App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mikakrooswijk.led"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:stitch-android-sdk:4+'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:stitch-android-services-mongodb-local:4+'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer from @shizhen didn't work for me. What did work in the end was renaming a library provided by mongoDB. I renamed the library `libmongoc_embedded.so` to  `libmongo_embedded_capi.so` and it works perfectly.

My assumtion is that this is the same library with a different name. It was changed in the download from mongoDB but not in the Java code, mongoDB Mobile is still in beta. I do not know a lot about mongoDB Mobile or Stitch so this might not be true, but it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I don't think this is the proper "solution". According to your error message, you need the JNA in path. so it is wired to hear that without JNA dependencies, your app can work well.

Comment: I agree that this is not a proper solution, or even a solution at all. I've gotten in touch with the MongoDB Mobile team and told them the problem i'm running into.  I'll keep this post updated when the respond.

Answer (score 1):

From below error log

> Setting 'jna.library.path' system property

It looks you miss the JNA dependencies for your project.

**Try below steps:**

- Add JNA dependencies into your `build.gradle`

  ```
  dependencies {
      ...
      // JNA dependency
      implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.5.0'
      ...
  }
  ```
- Include the `libjnidispatch.so` shared library for all the Android ABIs that your project supports.

  - Navigate to [JNA libraries](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/releases).
  - Under Version 4.5.0, download the zip archive
  - Unzip the package, navigate to `jna-4.5.0/dist/` directory. `libjnidispatch.so` for different ABIs can be extracted from respective jar file. The mapping is as below illustrated in below table.

    ```
    | JNA ABI             | Android ABI   |
    | ------------------- | ------------- |
    | android-aarch64.jar | arm64-v8a     |
    | android-armv7.jar   | armeabi-v7a   |
    | android-x86-64.jar  | x86_64        |
    | android-x86.jar     | x86           |
    ```
  - Put the `libjnidispatch.so` into the mapped Android ABI folder, for example, `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86` and `x86_64`.